# Why does my container not contain DB data after I commit it?

Tags: docker, postgresql, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL container that already contains development data. I can see the data I have created, but when I `commit`, `push`, and `pull` the image, the data is not there.

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgis/postgis:11-2.5
MAINTAINER Me

# Contents of 20-init_db.sql:
# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;
# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;
COPY ./20-init_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/20-init_db.sql
COPY ./make_data.sh /make_data.sh
```

I create the container using the script below, and data is successfully populated.

```
#!/bin/bash

aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | \
    docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 23456789JQKA.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

aws ecr create-repository --repository-name dev_postgres --region us-east-1

# Make sure the build environment is clean
docker stop dev_postgres_container
docker rm dev_postgres_container
docker rmi dev_postgres_img

# Prepare the container
docker build -f postgres.Dockerfile -t dev_postgres_img .
docker run -d --name dev_postgres_container \
    -e POSTGRES_DB=the_database \
    -e POSTGRES_USER=the_user \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=the_password \
    -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    dev_postgres_img
docker exec -it dev_postgres_container bash /make_data.sh

###
### This returns the correct number of users, so there is data in the container at this point.
###
docker exec -it dev_postgres_container /usr/bin/psql -U the_user the_database -c "select count(*) from auth_user;"

# Commit the container state and save it to Amazon ECR:
docker commit $(docker ps -q --filter "name=dev_postgres_container") 23456789JQKA.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev_postgres:11-2.5-with-data

# Also tag it with "latest" and the timestamp
docker tag 23456789JQKA.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev_postgres:11-2.5-with-data 23456789JQKA.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev_postgres:latest-with-data
docker tag 23456789JQKA.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev_postgres:11-2.5-with-data 23456789JQKA.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev_postgres:$( date -u +%Y%m%d_%H%MZ )-with-data

# Push
docker push 23456789JQKA.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev_postgres --all-tags
```

However, when I pull the container in an isolated environment, there's no data:

```
brew install virtualbox
brew install multipass
sudo multipass set local.driver=virtualbox
multipass launch --name ubuntu2
multipass mount ~/.aws ubuntu2:/home/ubuntu/.aws
multipass mount ./db ubuntu2:/home/ubuntu/db
multipass exec ubuntu2 -- bash /home/ubuntu/db/test_db_container.sh

### Contents of test_db_container.sh are below: ###

curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sudo sh get-docker.sh

sudo apt-get install -y awscli

# Pull Docker container:
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | \
    sudo docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 23456789JQKA.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
sudo docker pull 23456789JQKA.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev_postgres:latest-with-data

sudo docker run -d --name the_db 23456789JQKA.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev_postgres:latest-with-data

###
### The auth_user table does not exist.
###
sudo docker exec -it the_db /usr/bin/psql -U the_user the_database -c "select count(*) from auth_user;"

sudo docker history 23456789JQKA.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev_postgres:latest-with-data

## Result:
IMAGE          CREATED        CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
854dbef239c2   23 hours ago   postgres                                        70B
4b1bd66a8d33   23 hours ago   COPY ./make_data.sh /make_data.sh               3.03kB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      23 hours ago   COPY ./20-init_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-ini…   188B      buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      23 hours ago   MAINTAINER Me                                   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
[...]
```

Side note: I've considered creating a data volume container, but this method seemed simpler and better documented.

Other side note: I can't add the data in the Dockerfile because Postgres needs to be running before data can be inserted.

Why isn't `docker commit` saving the state of my container? Why does the image not contain data?

Comment: It's likely because the data volume is a .... volume. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377876/docker-postgres-with-initial-data-is-not-persisted-over-commits)

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I didn't realize the PostgreSQL container set `/var/lib/postgresql/data` as a volume. The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29956964/1477364), although the more I read, the more it looks like a data-only container is the best practice for this. (Post your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.)

Comment: Cool. Happy to hear that. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments under the main thread the solution was similar to the one suggested in [this existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377876/docker-postgres-with-initial-data-is-not-persisted-over-commits) answer. It boils down to the data directory being a volume and hence living outside of the context of the container being modified/committed.